# Adding navbar buttons to react-native-navigation while using react-native-meteor

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) in combination with [react-native-meteor](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor). Since Meteor 1.3 it's recommended to use createContainer method when using React. However, if I remove 'export default' from class definition and move it to export default createContainer(params=>{...}, MyClass), I loose definition of nav bar buttons. How I should write it to not loose definition of my nav bar buttons? Thanks :)

Here is the whole code of my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Meteor, { createContainer } from 'react-native-meteor';

class TestScreen extends Component {
    static navigatorButtons = {
        rightButtons: [{
            title: 'Reset',
            id: 'resetButton'
        }, {
            title: 'Submit',
            id: 'submitButton'
        }]
    };
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(
            this));
    }
    render() {
        return ( < View > < Text > Some text < /Text>
      </View > );
    }
    onNavigatorEvent(event) {
        if (event.type == 'NavBarButtonPress') {
            if (event.id == 'resetButton') {
                // reset here
            }
            if (event.id == 'submitButton') {
                // submit here
            }
        }
    }
}
export default createContainer(params => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('records');
    return {
        records: Meteor.collection('records').findOne(),
    };
}, TestScreen);
```

Comment: My knowledge of the "static" sugar is limited, are you sure you want to use it in this case? You could just provide a "get" method to retrieve the variables.

Comment: That's what documentation of react-native-navigation suggests. Is there any other way how to define nav bar buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them dynamically on navigator:

```
this.props.navigator.setButtons({
  rightButtons: [
    { title: 'Reset', id: 'resetButton' },
    { title: 'Submit', id: 'submitButton' }
  ]
});
```